# Unable to cast object of type 'Dictionary`2[System.String,ClauseEnumDocument]' to type 'List`1[System.Object]'

Tags: c#, .net, list, dictionary, bson

This class to be serialized for writing in Mongo generates the following Excpetion:

```
"An error occurred while deserializing the Contratti property of class Repository.NoSql.Documents.DocFolderDocument: An error occurred while deserializing the Clause property of class Repository.NoSql.Documents.DocFolderDocument.ContratctDocument: An error occurred while deserializing the KeysValue property of class Repository.NoSql.Documents.DocumentsComposition.ClauseDocument: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,Repository.NoSql.Documents.DocFolderDocument.ClauseEnumDocument]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]'"
```

This is the class ClauseDocument:

```
public class ClauseDocument
    {
        [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
        public CodeDesc<string> CodeDesc { get; set; }
        [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
        public string ClauseHtmlBody { get; set; }
        [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
        public string ClauseBodyRtf { get; set; }
        [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
        public string ClauseBody { get; set; }
        [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
        public Int32 Number { get; set; }
        [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
        public List<ClauseKeysValueDocument> KeysValue { get; set; } -> generate the exception
        [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
        public List<ProductDocument> ProductDocument { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the class ClauseKeysValueDocument:

```
public class ClauseKeysValueDocument
    {
        [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
        public string ListSeparatorValues { get; set; }
        [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
        private Dictionary<string, ClauseEnumDocument> _ValueListDict { get; set; }
        //should be Dictionary<int, ClauseEnumDocument> but in .net core 3.1 seralization of dictionary is supported only for dictionary<string, T>
        //ref: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30524

        [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
        public object  ValueListDict
        {
            get { return 
                    _ValueListDict;
            }
            set { 
                var dictAsArray = (List<object>)value;
                var dict = new Dictionary<string, ClauseEnumDocument>();
                foreach (var i in dictAsArray)
                {
                    var item = (List<object>)i;
                    dict.Add(item[0].ToString(), (ClauseEnumDocument)item[1]);
                }
                _ValueListDict = dict;
            }
        }
        [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
        public String StateCode { get; set; }
        [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
        public String RecordStateCode { get; set; }
        [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
        [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
        public int ProgNumberToCancel { get; set; } //MANCA
        [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
        public Int32 ProgNumber { get; set; }
        [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
        public String Value { get; set; }
    }
```

To be honest I don't understand what the error is, I didn't do that code but I have to fix it, the application has .net core 3.1 architecture

Comment: Which line in the code throws the exception?

Comment: var dictAsArray = (List<object>)value; in the set of property ValueListDict

Comment: What's your "value" actual type? It's passed to the setter as an object.

Comment: Dictionary<string, ClauseEnumDocument>